If $ \int_0^{\infty}\frac{ax}{1+a^2+x^2}e^{-a^2x}\cos(a^2x)dx $ is convergent uniformly with respect to $ a\in(0,1] $.
$$
\mbox{Consider the integral}\quad
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ax}{1 + a^{2} + x^{2}}
{\rm e}^{-a^{2}x}\cos\left(a^{2}x\right){\rm d}x
$$

I want to consider the uniform convergence of it in the interval $\left(0,1\right]$.
It is easy to see that in $\left[b,1\right]$ with
$0 < b < 1 $, this integral is convergent.
However I cannot figure out the case that $a$ is near the point $0$.

Can you give me some hints or references ?.

We have
$${ax\over 1+a^2+x^2}e^{-a^2x}\cos(a^2x)\\ ={\sqrt{x}\over 1+a^2+x^2}\left [\sqrt{a^2x}\,e^{-a^2x}\right ]\cos(a^2x)$$ The function
$te^{-t^2}$ is bounded by ${1\over 2}$ as ${t\over 1+t^2}\le {1\over 2}.$  Hence $$\left | {ax\over 1+a^2+x^2}e^{-a^2x}\cos(a^2x)\right |\\ \le {1\over 2}{\sqrt{x}\over 1+a^2+x^2}\le {\sqrt{x}\over 2(1+x^2)}$$ As the function $\sqrt{x}/(1+x^2)$ is integrable, the integral is uniformly convergent with respect to all $a>0,$ $0<a\le 1$ in particular.  Indeed, the tails of the integrals with parameter $a$ are bounded by the tail of the integral of $\sqrt{x}/(1+x^2).$
Remark The same method can be used if $ax$ in the numerator is replaced by $a^\delta x=x^{1-\delta/2}(a^2x)^{\delta/2}$ for a fixed $0<\delta\le 1.$ However the integral $$\int\limits_1^\infty {x\over 1+a^2+x^2}e^{-a^2x}\cos(a^2x)\,dx$$ is not uniformly convergent. Indeed, we have
$$0\le {1\over x}-{x\over 1+a^2+x^2}={1+a^2\over x(1+a^2+x^2)}\le {2\over x^3}$$ Thus it suffices to study
$$\int\limits_1^\infty e^{-a^2x}\cos(a^2x)\,{dx\over x}$$ For any fixed $N>1$ we have
$$\int\limits_N^\infty e^{-a^2x}\cos(a^2x)\,{dx\over x}=\int\limits_{a^2N}^\infty e^{-x}\cos x\,{dx\over x}$$ There is $0<b<1$ so that $\int\limits_b^\infty e^{-x}\cos x{dx\over x}=:c\neq 0.$ Choose $a$ so that $a^2N=b.$ Then $a<1$ and $\int\limits_{a^2N}^\infty e^{-x}\cos x\,{dx\over x}=c\neq 0.$ Hence the tails are not convergent to $0,$ uniformly with respect to $0<a\le 1.$
